# Node.js bcrypt working when normal but not working when using with Electron

Tags: electron, bcrypt

When i am using the without electron it's work like a charm but when i am trying to do hash with electron it's not working at all i just even require

```
    App threw an error during load
Error: The module '/home/thalinda/Desktop/real/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:740:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/thalinda/Desktop/real/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/thalinda/Desktop/real/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:239:3)
A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
Uncaught Exception:
Error: The module '/home/thalinda/Desktop/real/node_modules/bcrypt/lib/binding/bcrypt_lib.node'
was compiled against a different Node.js version using
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 57. This version of Node.js requires
NODE_MODULE_VERSION 64. Please try re-compiling or re-installing
the module (for instance, using `npm rebuild` or `npm install`).
    at process.module.(anonymous function) [as dlopen] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:740:18)
    at Object.module.(anonymous function) [as .node] (ELECTRON_ASAR.js:166:20)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:620:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:559:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:658:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/thalinda/Desktop/real/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:6:16)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/thalinda/Desktop/real/node_modules/bcrypt/bcrypt.js:239:3)
```

Comment: Electron comes with its own version of Node, so when you're using `bcrypt` with an Electron app, it is using that version. When you use it outside of electron, it will use another version of Node, which it apparently likes more. It appears to prefer an older Node. You might need to downgrade Electron (or upgrade bcrypt if possible?). What version of Electron are you on?

Comment: Hello thank you very much for replying as you said it's the version and it's forced me to use a alternative library `  "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "electron": "^3.0.8",
    "mysql": "^2.16.0",
    "node-php-password": "^0.1.2"
  }` still i think it's very good if i can use it this are my version information